# Search for all points within a bounding box

Tags: postgis

I've already checked all previous similar question. I'm asking again just because I need to be more specific by describing the database structure I am working with.

```
CREATE TABLE stores (name varchar, geom geometry);
CREATE INDEX geoid ON stores USING gist((geom::geography))

INSERT INTO stores VALUES ('Store name', 'ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(16.123, 51.321), 4326)')
/* where 16.123 is longitude and 51.321 is latitude */
```

Until now we only perform search-in-radius (circle) queries, with the following sintax

```
SELECT ST_X(geom) as longitude, ST_Y(geom) as latitude FROM stores WHERE
ST_DWithin("stores"."geom", ST_MakePoint(15, 50)::geography, 10000)
/* where 15 is longitude, 50 is latitude and 10000 is the radius in meters */
```

As stated in the title, now we also need to perform some query to get all stores within a bounding box, starting from lat_north, lng_east, lat_south, lng_west.

Should I use the ST_DWithin function again? Maybe with the ST_MakeEnvelope. I'm also confused by the use of the geography cast in the "radius" query.

Comment: With one of the geometries passed in as `GEOGRAPHY`, the other is auto-cast to `GEOGRAPHY` under the hood. This allows for proximity searches in *meter* rather than *unit of CRS* (*degrees* in this case). This is reflected by the index you added.

Comment: It's faster to load the data and then index it

Answer (score 2):

Please, please make sure you [add a spatial index](https://postgis.net/workshops/postgis-intro/indexing.html) to your table, then you can use the [`&&` operator](https://postgis.net/docs/geometry_overlaps.html).

```
SELECT ST_X(geom) as longitude, ST_Y(geom) as latitude FROM stores 
WHERE geom && ST_MakeEnvelope(left, bottom, right, top, 4326)
```

Comment: I would emphasize that && makes comparison by bounding boxes and while it gives exact result for points it may select some additional geometries from other geometry types.

Comment: Actually I forgot to mention the spatial index. Check the question, I've just edit

Comment: could you please clarify how to use the && operator in this particular situation? Unfortunately, the example in the link you provided is not clear to me

Comment: @user30184 - OP has points and boxes `&&` will work just fine

Comment: Sure yes but it does not make harm to know that with linestrigs and polygons `&&` may lead to extra hits. Some other user may apply this answer to another problem in the future.